# Battery not charging? (Even after SMC reset)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

So, I've seen a couple topics like this that already exist, but none solved my problem. I plug in my charge to my 13-Inch MacBook Air, Early 2015, and the LED light did not turn on, and the battery icon on my mac says that the battery is not charging. I am 8% right now, and am not losing power, but not getting any either.

I tried the obvious: Unplugging and plugging the charger to my computer, unplugging and replugging it into the outlet, both at the same time, flipping the charger upside down, restarting my computer, and tried every different outlet in my house. I have a few extra charger extenders, (where you take out the two prongs and replace it with a longer cable) so I tried changing those out, and changing back to a two prong, all with no luck.

It was working perfectly this morning, and I haven't done anything to my computer or charger, such as spilling something on them or dropping them. I don't know whether the problem is with the computer or the charger, and can't test it because I only have one of each.

So I looked up this problem, and basically every source said to do an SMC reset, and I basically tried every single variation of it I could find.

I would be happy to provide any other specs that you think are necessary to know.

Keep in mind when explaining this, that I am very tech-savvy when it comes to software, but I know almost nothing about hardware or electronics.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. The computer socket where the charger was going in had some pencil marks in it. My friend just used a pencil eraser inside it, and then blew out the rubber, and it works like new.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another charger? If yes and if that works, maybe your first charger was damaged. Maybe there's a wire inside of it has broken or something, or the charger became loose (in wires or plug). But if you tried another charger and nothing happened, maybe the problem is in you laptop.

Comment: As I said in the question:

"It was working perfectly this morning, and I haven't done anything to my computer or charger, such as spilling something on them or dropping them. I don't know whether the problem is with the computer or the charger, and can't test it because I only have one of each."